# Tables not updating on loading in mobile devices

Tags: tabulator

On load my app constructs a few Tabulator tables, then proceeds to fill them via the *setData()* function with data from the server via ajax calls. Setting ajax data within the constructor was not working for me so this formed a suitable workaround.

When I run this app on Google Chrome desktop, the tables are shown correctly constructed with the data in there. On iPhone/iPad Safari/Google Chrome, the tables are correctly constructed in terms of column layout but are empty. They require me to click on the table header in order the show the data. This problem is only at page load as all further *setData()* calls work as expected following page load. Just wondering if anyone else has experienced something similar.

**Version info:**

- Tabulator 4.1

- Safari 11.0.3 til most recent version

- Chrome 70.0.3538.75 (iPhone/iPad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your table visible when it is first built? if not you will need to call the ***redraw*** function once your table has loaded, This is because tabulator needs to be visible in order to calculate how to layout the table:

```
table.redraw(true);
```

If that isnt the case, could you raise this as a bug on the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator) and i will get a patch out for it this evening (make sure you post your full table constructor so i can replicate the issue as best as possible)

Comment: Oli, yes it is visible, only the data is empty. I will move over to Github, thanks